# Taking Roissy Bus from Place Charles de Gaulle Etoile to CDG Terminal 2

Tags: airport-transfer, paris, cdg

I am confused because on they Way to Paris from CDG I took Roissy Bus to Opera. It did not stop at CdG Etoile. Today I am very busy going to CDG airport. Is there a stop at etoile? The web page is not clear about this.

Comment: @Vince you are right. I was in a hurry, I am in Paris and I need to leave in some hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [a flyer on the RATP website](http://www.ratp.fr/en/upload/docs/application/pdf/2010-11/depliant_roissybus.pdf) that says it only stops at Opera within Paris.

From The Place de l'Etoile, you have two options:

- taking the line 2 of the [Cars Air France](http://www.aeroportsdeparis.fr/ADP/en-GB/Passagers/Access-maps-car-parks/Paris-CDG/Access/public-transport/paris-cdg-car-air-france.htm). It is operated by a private company and goes directly yo Roissy. It is more expensive than the public transit system.
- connecting to the Roissybus or the RER B to go to the airport. For example, you can take the metro line 2 towards Nation, stop at La Chapelle and then connect on the RER B at the Gare du Nord.

Comment: +1: Metro 2 to La Chapelle and then RER B to Aeroport CDG is probably the best option. Or one can take RER A one station to Auber/Opera and then RoissyBus.

Comment: I went to the information counter and they printed a combination of RER A and B. It takes less then 60 minutes and no danger of a traffic jam. This sounds best to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion stems from the existence of two different bus services. [Roissybus](http://www.ratp.fr/en/ratp/r_61852/roissybus/), operated by the local transport authority RATP, connects Opéra to the Roissy CDG airport terminals. [Cars Air France](http://www.lescarsairfrance.com/en.html), operated by the French national airline, connects Étoile to CDG.

From Étoile by bus, you can take [Cars Air France line 2](http://www.lescarsairfrance.com/fileadmin/documents/accueil/L2_plan.pdf) (make sure you board a bus for Roissy, not for Orly). The bus departs from Avenue Carnot heading away from the Place. Buses run [every half-hour](http://www.lescarsairfrance.com/fileadmin/documents/accueil/L2_horaires.pdf) on the quarter-hour during daytime and take approximately one hour with a risk of traffic jams.

You can also take the train: take RER line A towards Boissy-Saint-Léger/Marne-la-Vallée (any train heading east), and change at the second stop Châtelet–Les Halles for a line B train to Roissy–Aéroport Charles de Gaulle (this is not the train on the opposite platform, you need to go up and down the stairs). The journey takes a little under an hour, with at least a train every 15 minutes and a risk of traffic disruptions.

The airport bus is a bit more expensive and a bit slower than the train, but more comfortable. The risk of delays is roughly the same; traffic jams are very common at peak hour but are managed, whereas major train service disruptions are less common but can be very disruptive.